# When to use READ_GSERVICES permission?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-permissions

I have an application which uses Google Play Services for GCM and ads. My last update added an in-app billing and I received a crash report for :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: 
Neither user 10237 nor current process has 
com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.
```

I never had this problem before, nor did I when I tested my application with IAP. It only happens on one device (Xperia Z, surely the same user). When I search for this permission, it is referred on the Google's doc only for Maps API which says it *"Allows the API to access Google web-based services."*. But it is not mentioned for GCM implementation, ADs or on the [Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) pages.

So, do I really **need** this permission? Or is it a bug (maybe from the manufacturer) on the device end?

Comment: Just saw [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22672846/1424030) on the right and it wasn't suggested when I wrote the question...

Comment: So what's the answer ? that Google works on fixing it?