# Google play out of date require 4452000 but found 4325034

Tags: android, google-play-services, ads

I am facing issue with google play service ads. I am using rev 17 version of play service in my app and using android 4.4.2 with installed play service version 4.8.20.

But getting a warning as below Google Play services out of date. Requires 4452000 but found 4325034. And ads are not displayed .

But works fine on Gingerbread device 2.3.x .

Earlier I was getting below error on kitkat and app was crashing.

java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10096 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.

Than I added READ_GSERVICES permission, its not crashing but ads are not displayed because of above out of date issue.

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672846/java-lang-securityexception-attempting-to-read-gservices-without-permission)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding permission to manifest file `com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.`

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with your `vending` and `gms` files from the google services library.

I would suggest locating these files and then manually installing them via the `adb` like so:

```
adb -install "C:\...\...\...\com.android.vending-4452000.apk
adb -install "C:\...\...\...\com.google.android.gms-4452000.apk
```

Comment: could not find above apk files on my system.

Comment: See if google play services is up to date in your sdk manager, if not I would suggest using GenyMotion emulator from which you can install Google Play Services on the emulator device and then update it from the emulator

Comment: open google play in your device, u will have to be online so that I would self-update itself to latest version.