# Google Play services out of date on Nexus 4

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm getting the logcat error:

> Google Play services out of date. Requires 4452000 but found 4323036

This is on an out of the box Nexus 4. I'm trying to run a few things through Play Services, including a map and an ad. That error above is from number 3. below.

In my build I've tried compiling numerous versions.

1. compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+
2. compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
3. compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4+'

Is this just a case of the phone needing updating? Should I be targetting a specific Play Services? And how do I gracefully handle issues like this, when (if) the phone being out of date is the problem?

***Update: I got the app and map working on the device when it eventually updated Google Play Services to the latest 6.whatever. So my question becomes more about the how to detect this issue and deal with it gracefully, rather than just letting the app error and close.**

Answer (score 0):

update google play service lib. and add below in your manifest -

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Don't add any value manually instead of @integer/google_play_services_version

Comment: I have that in my Manifest file. The build versions are in my gradle build file. I think Google Play Services needs to be included in there.

Comment: Well literally what should I have written as my compile in my gradle build file? I've tried the few I've written out there, I've updated Services and Repo on the SDK manager. I've got that bit in my Manifest.

Comment: refer this -http://stackoverflow.com/a/25092470/1501644. also update google-play app on your device

Comment: Adding none of these things has made a difference. If the issue is because the device isn't up to date then how can you check this and handle it gracefully?